# Floating inline divs in jQuery-ui accordion breaks variable width?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, width, jquery-ui-accordion

I am creating a schedule with an accordion that will have titles composed of information returned from a database query.  I need to be able to put several discrete elements in the title (a name, an ID number, a date, a time). When I put divs into the title link they display vertically.  I want them to display horizontally.  So I added a float:left; to them, but that breaks the accordion.  Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="schedule1">
    <h3 class="accordionTitle">
        <a href="#" class="accordionLink">
            Title
        </a>
    </h3>
    <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In pellentesque etc...
    </div>
</div>
<br /><br /><br />
<div id="schedule2">
    <h3 class="accordionTitle">
        <a href="#" class="accordionLink">
            <div>
                <div class="inline">title</div>
                <div class="inline">text</div>
                <div class="inline">in</div>
                <div class="inline">inline</div>
                <div class="inline">divs</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </h3>
    <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In pellentesque etc...
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.accordionLink {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.inline {
    float: left;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#schedule1, #schedule2').accordion({ 
        header: "h3",
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        fillSpace: true
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
.inline {
    display: inline-block;
    /* "float: left" must be removed */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just put the items coming back from the database in spans, and don't float them:

http://jsfiddle.net/MLatzke/r3SdE/

If you need to keep them as divs, you can also put a clearfix (via http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) on the parent div:

http://jsfiddle.net/MLatzke/rk2Xn/